# How to extract date from multiple transaction receipts in python having no pattern

Tags: python, ocr, python-tesseract, data-extraction, html-content-extraction

I have multiple transaction receipts and am trying to extract the invoice amount from each of these receipts. The problem is that the `ocr` I am using is not being able to capture certain amounts from the document. I have used pillow and `pytesseract` and `pdf2image` to convert the `pdf` documents to images and then used `ocr` to extract data from these images. I then convert the text into `ocr` `html` files to extract data using keywords and locations. However, certain information has not been extracted from the `pdf`. Please help me solve this.

Comment: Hi @Developer, if you are not able to achieve this with python and you can try with Microsoft OneNote. Just paste the image at a blank page and right-click over it to "Copy the text of this image" and that's it!!! You can paste thousands of images

Comment: Hi @dbz. Thanks, but i must use python